# Visual Basic 2013 RegEx

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio

How can I get only the Name?

"Hello **Name**!"

```
Dim r As New Regex("Hello (.*)! :)")
            Dim matches As MatchCollection = r.Matches(Chat)
            For Each m As Match In matches
                MsgBox("Hi " & m.ToString & " and welcome back!")
            Next
```

(Chat is the last Chatmessage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get only name, you should use `Groups`. And if you really want to match `:)`, you must escape `)` by using `\`:

```
Dim Chat As String = "Hello Name!"
Dim r As New Regex("Hello (.*)! :\)")
Dim matches As MatchCollection = r.Matches(Chat)
For Each m As Match In matches
   m.Groups(1).Value
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do a string replace for **Hello** and the **!** as you know these are fixed??

I don't know VB, but a REGEX in other language should be **Hello (\S+)!**